# Testing Contract: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether

I am writing a testing file for my coin flip project here is the beginning of the coin flip project:

contract CoinFlip {

```
address payable player;

address payable casino;
uint256 public casinoDeposit;
uint256 betAmount;
uint256 maxBet = .001 ether;
bytes32 commitHash;
uint gameTimeOut;
uint256  matchBetTimeOut;
uint256 revealTimeOut;
uint256 result;
bool win;
address payable contractAddress = address(this);

constructor () public payable{
    require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    casinoDeposit = msg.value;
}
```

Here is the testing file:

contract CoinFlipTest {
CoinFlip v;

```
function beforeAll() public {
    // create a new instance of Value contract
    v = new CoinFlip();
}
```

Every time I try to run the testing file I get this error. I would appreciate some help on what I am doing wrong:
✘ Before all
Error Message:
"Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "transactionHash": "0x0e839950a7737797d4c9fca76adb24d1ec0ff7d07b3b87eea5c3a8487d123043", "transactionIndex": 0, "blockHash": "0x9cc0f6017494c03c53ebbe39aef033623ed7f6e6937c6d376b7c3a0d78392b86", "blockNumber": 8, "gasUsed": 5000000, "cumulativeGasUsed": 5000000, "status": false, "to": "0xd2a5bC10698FD955D1Fe6cb468a17809A08fd005", "events": {} }"

Answer (score 1):

First of all in contract `CoinFlip` you need to have the following method in order to allow the incoming ether transfers:

```
receive() external payable {}
```

Secondly method `beforeAll` in contract `CoinFlipTest` is failing, because when you are creating the instance of contract `CoinFlip` you're not passing ethers to it and you have the following condition in the constructor which cause the error: `require(msg.value == 1 ether);` which says you have to pass exactly one ether when creating instance of this contract. You need to replace:

```
v = new CoinFlip();
```

With:

```
v = new CoinFlip{value: 1 ether}();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I added: 
receive() external payable {} to my main file and 
v = new CoinFlip{value: 1 ether}(); to my testing file and I am still getting the same error. Do you have any more tips on what it might be?

Comment: Did you made sure that contract ```CoinFlipTest``` actually have 1 ether to make the creation possible? Don't forget that ```CoinFlipTest``` is the creator of contract ```CoinFlip```, so he need to have the needed eth balance for the creation.

Comment: no i actually dont have 1 ether in my test account, how should I write it in my code? thank you so much for your help

Comment: Well add this ```constructor () public payable { }``` to contract ```CoinFlipTest``` and when creating instance of it you can select in remix to pass ether value. Then that contract should have ethers balance to create the other contract.

Comment: Did you made it?

Comment: I put this in my CoinFlipTest: 
`contract CoinFlipTest {`
    `CoinFlip v;`
    `constructor () public payable {}`
    
    `function beforeAll() public {`
        `v = new CoinFlip{value: 1 ether}();`
    }`
and im still getting the same error :(

Comment: Like I said, you need to make sure the contract ```CoinFlipTest``` has ether balance. Google how to charge a contract.